# Aggregate multiple dictionaries, add values together

Tags: c#

Is there any more efficient way to aggregate multiple dictionaries to one, and if there's a duplicate key, than add the values together? The dictionaries has at least 10000 keys-value pairs.

```
Dictionary<string, int>[] res;
Dictionary<string, int> aggregatedRes = res[0];
for (int i = 1; i < res.Length; i++)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> valuePair in res[i])
    {
        if (aggregatedRes.ContainsKey(valuePair.Key))
        {
            aggregatedRes[valuePair.Key] += valuePair.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            aggregatedRes.Add(valuePair.Key, valuePair.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

I found a lot of post on stackoverflow with similar question, but there if there was a duplicate key, they just drop one value of it, which is not good for me.

```
Dictionary 1
apple - 2
an - 1
I - 1
like - 3

Dictionary 2
apple - 3
car - 1
green - 1

Dictionary 3
apple - 1
green - 1
like - 1

Expected result:
apple - 6
an - 1
I - 1
like - 4
car - 1
green - 2
```

Comment: `I found a lot of post on stackoverflow with similar question, but there if there was a duplicate key, they just drop one value of it`. So, can't you modify them to sum up....

Comment: unfortunately not, if I can do it, I don't ask how to do

Comment: OK Then, how about posting a compilable code and showing your problem.. "A compilabe code + Sample input + what you get +  Expected output".

Comment: Probably more suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Those are written in LINQ, and I don't know, is possible to do this with it or how to do with it

Comment: the code which I posted, do this job, but I don't know, is there a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: One quick win in the current implementation is to use `TryGetValue` to prevent the key having to be looked up twice as is done in the lines `if (aggregatedRes.ContainsKey(valuePair.Key))
        {
            aggregatedRes[valuePair.Key] += valuePair.Value; `

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any magical way that's much better than what you're already doing. (Any tricks with LINQ will not improve performance.) A slight improvement might be to change your loop as follows:

```
for (int i = 1; i < res.Length; i++)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> valuePair in res[i])
    {
        int value;
        aggregatedRes.TryGetValue(valuePair.Key, out value);
        aggregatedRes[valuePair.Key] = value + valuePair.Value;
    }
}
```

If nothing else, it's a bit shorter.

What would really help was if we could do the lookup on `aggregatedRes` only once, but I see no way of doing that.

Comment: Well yes, there's no if statement inside it, that's nearly always better. Well, I'm not sure in your LINQ statement, because one of my friend did some benchmark on big data set with LINQ and with normal 'foreach' and 'for' statements and well, I still can't understand why was the LINQ appr. 33% faster than the other ones, when they did the same think...

Comment: @golddragon007: I'd be interested in seeing the LINQ formulation. Opinions must bow to measurements, of course. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested performance, but *a* way using linq would be to flatten the dictionaries (selectmany), group on all the keys and create a new dictionary, summing the group values:

```
var aggregatedRes  = (from d in res
            from kv in d 
            group kv by kv.Key)
        .ToDictionary(g=>g.Key, g=>g.Sum(kv=>kv.Value));
```

(For performance with large dictionaries, the above would work with parallelism as well by using `from d in res.AsParallel()`)